# How to ensure ng-repeat fills in table before my directive examines the table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, pagination

I am writing a custom table pagination directive that I want to work for any table (whether it be filled manually or by an ng-repeat).  Currently it works on a regular table, but when I add an ng-repeat to fill the table it shows no page numbers (i.e. it thinks there are no rows in the table).  I am assuming this problem is being caused because ng-repeat is inside the table on a  and is not actually filling in the table before my directive tries to examine it, so when my directive inspects the DOM it sees a table with no rows.  Is there a way to ensure that ng-repeat fills the table in before my code inspects the table?

here is my plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CHO6HbT4emM3VEwcNnzq?p=preview

and the code below describes the rest.

The following is my directive code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("mainModule");
myApp.directive("cndPaginateTable", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'Templates/Directives/paginatedTable.html',
        scope: {
            cndDefaultPageLength: '@',
            cndShowEnds: '@'
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.cndDefaultPageLength = scope.cndDefaultPageLength === undefined ? 10 : scope.cndDefaultPageLength;
        var rowCount = $(element).children('div').children('tbody').children('tr').length;      //how many rows are in main table (excluding any rows in nested tables)

        console.log(rowCount);
        var numberOfPages = Math.ceil(rowCount / scope.cndDefaultPageLength);
        scope.cndShowEnds;
        scope.cndPageNumbers = [];
        scope.max = 0;

        $(element).find('*').children('tr').each(function () {      //find the number of columns in the main table
            var count = $(this).children('td').length;
            if (count > scope.max) {
                scope.max = count;
            }
        });

        for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
            scope.cndPageNumbers.push(i);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Here is the template I am using:

```
<div ng-transclude>

</div>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <td colspan="{{max-1}}"></td>
    <td>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button ng-if="cndShowEnds" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cndTablePaginationNav('first')">First</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-repeat="pageNumber in cndPageNumbers" ng-click="cndTablePaginationNav('{{pageNumber}}')">{{pageNumber}}</button>
                <button ng-if="cndShowEnds" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cndTablePaginationNav('last')">Last</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
```

And here is my HTML I am testing the directive with:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <table class="table" cnd-paginate-table cnd-show-ends="true">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                first name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                last name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                job title
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr ng-repeat="test in testTableData">
                        <td>
                            test.firstName
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            test.lastName
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            test.jobTitle
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that all I had to do was add a $timeout surrounding my directive, and it would wait until the view was rendered!

here is the result and it works:

```
var myApp = angular.module("mainModule");
myApp.directive("cndPaginateTable", function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'Templates/Directives/paginatedTable.html',
    scope: {
        cndDefaultPageLength: '@',
        cndShowEnds: '@'
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(
            function () {

                scope.cndDefaultPageLength = scope.cndDefaultPageLength === undefined ? 5 : scope.cndDefaultPageLength;
                var rowCount = $(element).children('div').children('tbody').children('tr').length;      //how many rows are in main table (excluding any rows in nested tables)

                var numberOfPages = Math.ceil(rowCount / scope.cndDefaultPageLength);
                scope.cndShowEnds;
                scope.cndPageNumbers = [];
                scope.max = 0;

                $(element).find('*').children('tr').each(function () {      //find the number of columns in the main table
                    var count = $(this).children('td').length;
                    if (count > scope.max) {
                        scope.max = count;
                    }
                });

                for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
                    scope.cndPageNumbers.push(i);
                }
            }, 0);

        console.log(scope.cndPageNumbers);
    }
}
});
```